# Having issues with mixing dynamic & static images

Tags: html, image-scaling

I'm trying to create a gallery inside of a frame that has a set of images. The first image in the gallery I'm trying to have a dynamic image which has a height of the window, and a coresponding width that doesn't change the aspect ratio of the image. I've found I can do that with this code:

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; left:0px; right:0px;z-index:1">
<img src="IMAGENAME.jpg" height="100%"/></div>
```

Next I want to add an image to the right of this dynamicly sized image which has a fixed size, and then I want to add another image to the right of that with a fixed size etc.

As the windows is displayed on different screens I want the static images to always be touching the boarder of the dynamic image.

I've tried various ways of doing this but I'm pretty much stuck, can anyone help? The easiest way would be to get the window height then multiply that by a fixed amount (aspect ratio) and then offset the other images by that amount, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code in order to float all your images next to the dynamic one:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.thumbnail 
{
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; left:0px; right:0px;z-index:1">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="IMAGENAME.jpg" height="100%">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="img1.jpg">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="img2.jpg">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="img3.jpg">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="img4.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked with a small tweak. I had to change the "width" in the div tag to a value, ie 7000px   

The only issue I have is that I want to vertically center the images. Any help?